# Broken libc.so.6 after WPS office (alpha) installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc, libc

My OS is Ubuntu LTS 16.04 
After installing the latest WPS Office rpm package, it seems that I somehow screwed the dynamic linker settings that is causing `exec of init (/sbin/init) failed!!!: Accessing a corrupted shared library kernel panic - Not syncing :Attempting to kill init!`, as far as I understand the problem.

I get the following error on almost any command I run:
`apt: relocation error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_find_dso_for_object, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference`

By using LiveCD I mounted the OS folders and did 'chroot' to the native installation, but I have no idea how to fix the problem.

UPDATE: I did  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/lib` and I managed to run some of the applications, without apt-get and yum for instance :/

Comment: It seems that the dynamic linker ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 used at startup does not match.

Answer (score 0):

> I override some kernel library that is no longer compatible with my kernel

This has absolutely *nothing* to with kernel. There is also no such thing as "kernel library".

The problem is a mismatch between `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` (which apparently got updated) and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` (which didn't).

You want to restore the `libc6` package from your rescue CD.

Comment: You are right about the first statement, nothing to do with "kernal libraries", in the beginning I have misunderstood the problem. It seems that the dynamic linker configuration is screwed up. When I set a system variable  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/lib` some of the applications started working again. The problem is the apt-get still doesn't work due to a list of missing dependencies. And I tried to copy from the Live CD the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/, but without any success.